# lodash strange behavior with _.upperFirst

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash's upperFirst method to capitalize the first letter of a single worded string in a React app. This method does capitalize the first letter as expected, but given a string with multiple uppercase letters, the method will lowercase all but the first.

For example:

```
_.upperFirst('helloWorld') => 'Helloworld' expected: 'HelloWorld'
```

The strange thing is that using this method on lodash's site, the function behaves as expected i.e. returns `'HelloWorld'`

I'm not sure why this wouldn't be the case in my app.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I get the expected result.  Which version of lodash are you using?  I tested with 4.17.4.  You can find your version using `_.VERSION`

Comment: Same here. Are you using any other methods on the string that might be lowering all the other letters?

Comment: Look at this thread:  https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1995.  In particular, look at the last comment by jdalton on Feb 13, 2016.

Comment: I feel dumb. Realized i was importing like so: `import upperFirst from 'lodash/capitalize';` Resulting in me actually calling the capitalize method instead. :|

Comment: @jamesvphan oops :)

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect way of importing.

Did:
`import upperFirst from 'lodash/capitalize';`
Instead of 
`import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst';`